# How do you sort questions by most viewed, unanswered (Most viewed at top) for a particular tag?

Tags: support

I'd like to work through a list of unanswered questions for a particular tag. But would like to start with the most viewed first.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't believe you can sort by view count at all. It's been asked for before but [was declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113042/can-we-have-a-sort-by-view-count).

Comment: @Nick That's a shame. I would have thought the high view count for these particular questions have come from search engines results. Therefore, If these questions could be answered It would benefit a greater amount of people?

Comment: I guess you could settle for sorting by upvotes. It's not exactly view counts but every upvote does imply a pair of eyeballs. And it weeds out the questions that should probably not be answered, a total view count really does not do that.

Comment: @Gimby Not a bad suggestion, I'll give it a go. thanks

Comment: as said on the [meta-tag:status-declined] feature request provided by @Nick, you can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118692/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is search by view thresholds. For example you can search for

```
[java] views:50000 answers:0
```

Meaning:

> Unanswered questions tagged with "java" having at least 50,000 views

There are currently six such questions: [link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+views%3A50000+answers%3A0&searchOn=1). You still won't be able to order the results by views within those results, but you know that all those questions have tons of views.

This technique was suggested when a similar question was asked on the main meta site: [How do I sort the questions by the number of views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views)